# PHP and Bing Translation API

Tags: php, translation, access-token, azure-marketplace

I've registered with Azure Marketplace, I have a client ID and a client "secret", but everything I've tried so far nonetheless results in a "400 Bad Request" error.  Thanks very much!

Here is a rather basic sample of the code I've been trying (I've redacted the Client ID and Secret Value).  I'm operating with the understanding that the post variables can be passed through the URL request... I hope that's correct.

```
$authURL = 'http://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={CLIENT_ID VALUE HERE}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET VALUE HERE}&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com';
$chpre = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chpre, CURLOPT_URL, $authURL );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$xpre = curl_exec($chpre);

$texttobetranslated = "الذي تقدمه";
$BingURL = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" . $texttobetranslated . "&from=ar&to=en";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $BingURL );
$x = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Hi User, instead, why don't you *show* us what you've done, then ask specific questions about the code, and then we can better help you. This site isn't really about writing code for people but is instead for helping when they're stuck (which you are... you just need to post your code:) Good luck!

Comment: Do you need to pass the token into the 2nd curl request?  http://wangpidong.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-use-new-bing-translator-api-with.html

Comment: I didn't notice that, so thanks... but adding $TokenHeader = "Authorization:bearer " . $xpre; and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $TokenHeader); didn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more help I can be, but that blog article is fairly recent. If you have access to a unix machine (Mac/Linux), I'd suggest running through his examples with your own values. Make sure the API works and all your keys work, then that will help you tell if it's your code that's broken or your keys/tokens. My thought is narrow down the problem. Hope that helps!

Comment: Why dont you try following implementation
https://code.google.com/p/micrsoft-translator-php-wrapper/ Demo is given in http://renjith.co.in/translate/

Comment: this solution worked for me pretty well: [Using BING Translator (Version 2) from PHP](http://svendeswan.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/using-bing-translator-version-2-from-php/) As said in the post, CURL needs to be installed and running on the server. Cheers,
Sven

Answer (score 6):

I have createde little PHP class that is easy to use and easy to integrate to any PHP project. You can find it [here](https://github.com/torayeff/phpbing). This is code:

```
  <?php
    class BingTranslation
    {
        public $clientID;
        public $clientSecret;

        public function __construct($cid, $secret)
        {
            $this->clientID = $cid;
            $this->clientSecret = $secret;
        }

        public function get_access_token()
        {   
            //if access token is not expired and is stored in COOKIE
            if(isset($_COOKIE['bing_access_token']))
                return $_COOKIE['bing_access_token'];

            // Get a 10-minute access token for Microsoft Translator API.
            $url = 'https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13';
            $postParams = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='.urlencode($this->clientID).
            '&client_secret='.urlencode($this->clientSecret).'&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com';

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postParams);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
            $rsp = curl_exec($ch); 
            $rsp = json_decode($rsp);
            $access_token = $rsp->access_token;

            setcookie('bing_access_token', $access_token, $rsp->expires_in);

            return $access_token;
        }

        public function translate($word, $from, $to)
        {
            $access_token = $this->get_access_token();
            $url = 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?text='.$word.'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to;

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization:bearer '.$access_token));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
            $rsp = curl_exec($ch); 

            preg_match_all('/<string (.*?)>(.*?)<\/string>/s', $rsp, $matches);

            return $matches[2][0];
        }

        public function translate2($word, $from, $tos)
        {
            //translates 1 word to several languages
            //$tos is array of languages to translate to
            //returns array of translations as $result['en']=>'Hello'

            $access_token = $this->get_access_token();

            $result[$from] = $word;

            foreach($tos as $to)
            {
                $url = 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?text=hello&from='.$from.'&to='.$to;

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization:bearer '.$access_token));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
                $rsp = curl_exec($ch); 

                preg_match_all('/<string (.*?)>(.*?)<\/string>/s', $rsp, $matches);

                $result[$to] = $matches[2][0];
            }

            return $result;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Put this code at your header part.. 
This Works Perfect For Me..Enjoy it

```
<div id='MicrosoftTranslatorWidget' class='Light' style='color:white;background-color:#555555'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
setTimeout(function(){{
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.type='text/javascript';
s.charset='UTF-8';
s.src=((location && location.href && location.href.indexOf('https') == 0)?'https://ssl.microsofttranslator.com':'http://www.microsofttranslator.com')+'/ajax/v3/WidgetV3.ashx?siteData=ueOIGRSKkd965FeEGM5JtQ**&ctf=False&ui=true&settings=Manual&from=';
var p=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.documentElement;
p.insertBefore(s,p.firstChild); 
}},0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest code that is working for me based on latest credentials from Bing Translation API:

```
<?php 
$key1 = "??????";  //enter your azure key here
$endpoint = 'https://languagetranslationservice.cognitiveservices.azure.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken';  //enter your azure end point here
$from = "en";  //Support Languages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/language-support
$to = "te";
$inputStr = "welcome to paradise";

function getToken($key1, $endpoint)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data_string = json_encode('{body}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ' . $key1
        )
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $strResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $strResponse;
}

// function for translation
function curlRequest($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $curlResponse;
}

//start translation
$accessToken = getToken($key1, $endpoint);
$params = "text=" . urlencode($inputStr) . "&to=" . $to . "&from=" . $from . "&appId=Bearer+" . $accessToken;
$translateUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?$params";
$curlResponse = curlRequest($translateUrl);
$output = simplexml_load_string($curlResponse);
echo $output;
?>
```